# How to get selected radio button in group via c#

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How to get the index of the selected Radiobutton control that is located inside a stackpanel (parent container) than border than radio button via c#?

here is what i am got after searching and trying

```
 for (int i = 0; i < this.selective.Children.Count; i++)
            {

                if (this.selective.Children[i].GetType().Name == "RadioButton")
                {
                    RadioButton radio = (RadioButton)this.selective.Children[i];
                    if ((bool)radio.IsChecked)
                    {
                        //get checked indes name
                   }
               }
          }
```

but here i am having radio button inside border so how to achieve the same

here is my xaml

```
  <StackPanel Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="selective" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="462"   >

                    <Border  Margin="20,0,20,0" Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" >
                        <RadioButton GroupName="main1" x:Name="radio1"   Foreground="#FF030303"   Background="#FF0075A9" />
                    </Border>
                    <Border Margin="20,0,20,0" Grid.Row="2" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black" >

                        <RadioButton GroupName="main1" x:Name="radio2"   Foreground="#FF030303"   Background="#FF0075A9"  />
                    </Border>
    ....
```

so how to know which is checked ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may try something like that :

```
foreach (var radioButton in selective.Children.OfType<Border>().Select(b => b.Child).OfType<RadioButton>())
{
    if (((RadioButton)radioButton).IsChecked ?? false)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

## Updated Answer

Here is how you get index and name of the `RadioButton` :

```
var radioButtons = selective.Children.OfType<Border>().Select(b => b.Child).OfType<RadioButton>();
foreach (var radioButton in radioButtons)
{
    if (radioButton.IsChecked ?? false)
    {
        var name = radioButton.Name;
        var index = radioButtons.ToList().IndexOf(radioButton);
    }
}
```

Comment: how to get selected name and index from here @Chostakovitch

Comment: @SmartDeveloper What do you mean by `index` ? The index of the RadioButton in what ?

Comment: If there is one border for each RadioButton and that the index you want is the index of the border I will update my answer.

Comment: if there are 5 radio buttons and if third is selected than i want the 2 as output

Answer (score 0):

put `main1` instead of `this`

```
for (int i = 0; i < main1.selective.Children.Count; i++)
            {

                if (main1.selective.Children[i].GetType().Name == "RadioButton")
                {
                    RadioButton radio = (RadioButton)main1.selective.Children[i];
                    if ((bool)radio.IsChecked)
                    {
                        //get checked indes name
                   }
               }
          }
```

Comment: main1 does not exist in current context showing error there @Harshit Shrivastava